# How to load a web page into a full-fledged JavaScript-enabled DOM with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

What I need is to load a web page, let it run the way it would if opened in a browser (including JavaScript execution) and access it programmatically (like with document.getElement*) while not showing it to the user. How to do this with JavaScript in Chrome? I am trying do this inside a Tampermonkey user script actually.

Comment: just use a hidden iframe

Comment: This idea has already came into my mind, @dandavis - I am coding it this way right now but I am still curious if there are any better ideas.